# How to configure the elastic search endpoint so that graylog-ctl reconfigure does not overwrite it

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog2, amazon-elasticsearch

I am running graylog in AWS sourced from https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-images/tree/2.3/aws

I am using an external elastic search server (actually a hosted AWS Elastic search)

I have configured my graylog to run without elastic search but I have this problem:

When my public IP address changes I need to set the new external id...

1. I run graylog-ctl set-external-ip to set it
2. I run graylog-ctl reconfigure
3. This then overwrites the elasticsearch_hosts setting in the server.conf to point to the local ip address.

Is there a way to set the elasticsearch_hosts so that graylog-ctl reconfigure does not overwrite it?

So far I have found [this](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.3/pages/configuration/graylog_ctl.html#advanced-settings) and [this](https://github.com/Graylog2/omnibus-graylog2/blob/2.3/files/graylog-cookbooks/graylog/attributes/default.rb) but I don't know how these are referenced in the /etc/graylog-settings.json file.

What I really need is just someone to give me an example of one of these extra config parameters in operation and I'll be set...

Answer (score 0):

It was a very simple solution. I used the dns entry to set the external ip